# Por que a contagem continua do item anterior e não a partir do 0?

Tags: android, listview

Tenho um problema.

Fiz um método que calcula a contagem a partir de *clicks* na tela e jogue essa contagem em um `EditText`, mas o problema é que a contagem continua do item anterior e não do *0* na próxima linha.

Exemplo:

Se o item na `ListView` estiver no numero *5*, se eu clicar na outra linha, o numero será *6*.

Não sei se tem a ver com o "final" que eu coloquei no atributo `finalHolder` antes do método `setOnClickListener`.

Segue o código:

```
public class AdapterProduto extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context ctx;
    private List<Produto> listaProdutos;
    private int count;
    private int newCount;


    public AdapterProduto(Context ctx, List<Produto> listaProdutos) {
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.listaProdutos = listaProdutos;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return listaProdutos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int posicao) {

        return listaProdutos.get(posicao);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int posicao) {

        return listaProdutos.get(posicao).getId();
    }

    class MyViewHolder {
        TextView texto;
        ImageView soma;
        ImageView sub;
        ImageView excluir;
        EditText contagem;

        MyViewHolder(View v) {
            texto = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.textViewLista);
            soma = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImagemAddProduto);
            sub = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImagemSubProduto);
            excluir = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ImagemExcluir);
            contagem = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.contagemDePodutosDaLista);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int posicao, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        View row = convertView;

        MyViewHolder holder = null;

        if (row == null) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_lista, parent, false);

            holder = new MyViewHolder(row);
            row.setTag(holder);
            Log.i("Testando Holder", "Criando um novo row");
        } else {
            holder = (MyViewHolder) row.getTag();
            Log.i("Testando Holder", "Repassando");
        }
        Produto produto = listaProdutos.get(posicao);
        holder.texto.setText(produto.getConteudo());
        holder.soma.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_add);
        holder.sub.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_delete);
        holder.excluir.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_trash);
        holder.contagem.setId(R.id.contagemDePodutosDaLista);

        final MyViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
        holder.soma.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (v.getId() == finalHolder.soma.getId()){
                Log.i("Adapter", "Dentro do metodo de fazer a contagem");
                Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.contagem.getText().toString());
                count = count + 1;
                finalHolder.contagem.setText(String.valueOf(count));
                Log.i("Adapter", "Contagem efetuada");
            }
                else
                {

                    Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.contagem.getText().toString());
                    newCount = newCount + 1;
                    finalHolder.contagem.setText(String.valueOf(newCount));

                }
            }
        });

        return row;
    }

}
```

Comment: Não sei se entendi o que você quer ou seu real problema mas parece que o `finalHolder` não deveria ser `final` mesmo. Você experimentou tirá-lo para ver se resolve? Eu sei que do jeito que está realmente não faz sentido só não garanto se não tem outro problema.

Comment: que está recebendo `Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.contagem.getText().toString());` ?

Comment: Então estou tentando fazer a contagem na outra linha do ListView a partir do 0, mas ele pega a contagem da linha anterior.
Ja tentei tirar esse finalHolder, mas não funciona mesmo assim.

Comment: Juarez, nesta linha eu recebo 0. Deixei este valor no EditText.

Comment: Ok, mas `Integer.parseInt(stringMaséInteiro)` retorna um inteiro, ninguem está recebendo, e outra, vc nao precisa de um contador global para a classe, os nmrs estao sendo guardado no `contagem`, onde vc faz a conversão, acho q o certo seria `int count = Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.contagem.getText().toString());` em seguida `cont++;` e por fim atualiza o `contagem` `finalHolder.contagem.setText(String.valueOf(count));`

Comment: Julgo que o @Juarez em razão. Você está a usar sempre `count` que é uma variável global à classe. O que deve ser usado é o contador de cada linha ou seja `finalHolder.contagem`

Comment: Verdade Juarez, testei e deu certo!
Muito obrigado, comecei no android semana passada rs. Ainda tenho muito que aprender, valeu!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro, o seu código precisa seguir um padrão nas nomenclatura que utiliza, se não fica dificil fazer uma analise. ex.:
`soma`, `contagem`, etc... O mais interessante seria, como os livros que li sobre android é fazer da seguinte forma. `ivSoma`, `etContagem`, etc... Assim podemos compreender que `ivSoma` é um `ImageView`, logo facilita bastante na manutenção, pois as declarações são feitas geralmente no inicio da classe ou método, do jeito que você faz  precisamos dar `scroll` varias vezes para fazer identificação.

Respondendo a pergunta

```
if (v.getId() == finalHolder.soma.getId()){
   Log.i("Adapter", "Dentro do metodo de fazer a contagem");
   //repare que nenhuma variável está recebendo o valor na linha de baixo.
   Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.contagem.getText().toString());
   //contador count deve ser uma variável local/temporária, 
   //vc declarou ela como global da classe. 
   count = count + 1;
   finalHolder.contagem.setText(String.valueOf(count));
   Log.i("Adapter", "Contagem efetuada");
}
```

O certo seria

```
if (v.getId() == finalHolder.soma.getId()){
   Log.i("Adapter", "Dentro do metodo de fazer a contagem");
   int cont = Integer.parseInt(finalHolder.contagem.getText().toString());
   count++;
   finalHolder.contagem.setText(String.valueOf(count));
   Log.i("Adapter", "Contagem efetuada");
}
```

A mesma coisa serve para o código dentro do `else`.
Uma outra coisa, você declarou `contagem` como um `EditText`, ou vc torce pra ninguem entrar com uma `string` ou você desabilita entrada. Como é apenas para mostrar seria interessante declarar como `TextView`.

Comment: Muito bom, irei começar a utilizar padrões nas nomenclaturas.